# Relate Two Separate Breeze Data Sources (API and Breeze API Controller)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I have no idea of the correct Breeze terminology here but we have:

A WebAPI Breeze Controller and we have an API end point on another separate system. The Breeze controller has various entities for example People. The other system returns additional information about People entities that are conceptually related to the entities on the Breeze Controller.

For example Breeze API Controller returns a Person Brian. WebAPI controller returns number of absences and Brains ID.

Can we display a list of absences and show Brian's person details by relating the two together in Breeze as they share a common id. How can I tell Breeze that the two entities are related even though they come from different sources?

I am assuming I have to mess with the entities in someway and explain to Breeze they are related. However really not sure where to begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the advice from @Tyler Griffith about using multiple managers is probably the best way to go.

Given that you have different servers providing these different data sources, I must assume that you can't do distributed transactional updates across servers. For example, you wouldn't expect to be able to update Brian and his absences in the same save.

I'd be tempted to extend the `Person` type on the client with some custom properties to navigate from Brian in `em1` to Brian's absences in `em2`. Such properties would make your application code feel more natural.

While they would look like Breeze navigation properties, you'd be maintaining them yourself. Breeze wouldn't know anything about them.

It might not be as hard as you think. The Breeze `EntityManager.entityChanged` event gives you a single place to watch for changes in either manager and fix-up the navigations as the pertinent entities come and go.

See the documentation for extending entities with custom properties and the API docs for `EntityManager.entityChanged` (examples of usage appear throughout the DocCode sample).

Comment: No - they would be separate - the absences can't be updated from the application just viewed. I just wanted to make the fact they were coming from separate sources seamless to other developers. Assumed I would have to extend the entities in someway. I will have a look at trying that. Breeze is a very impressive piece of tech :)

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty new to breeze but your question reminds me of something i came across a couple weeks ago so i thought i would take a stab at answering.

based off of the information you provided what i would try to do is request the information from the external system from the one that has the breeze controller, then populate a server side Viewmodel with the data you get back completely flattened out into strings and ints and maybe dates if you need it (in my case i would do this in a service layer). then in your breeze controller return that viewmodel. this is the server side method that you will query in breeze to get the data you want back

like i said im pretty new so i hope this helped and wasn't a total waste of your time.

Comment: Yeah did consider just returning a query and joining it on server side. However there are potentially a lot more data sources that we want to join so I was hoping to not have to wrap all the calls at the server side as the client side work is easier for us to change.

Comment: In that case i think you have to look into implementing multiply entity managers http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/multiple-managers, so that you can have multiple service names, otherwise breeze will always try to look at a single server end point. If you didn't go with that approach i guess you could use jquery ajax posts and convert all the data you get back into observable properties (assuming your using knockout)